# Rails - Using Kaminari for pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I'm trying to get the next page link. How would I do this?
I get the following error when calling link_to_next_page

undefined method `link_to_next_page'

```
query = Posts.page(1).per(5).includes(author: :profile)

link = link_to_next_page(query, 'Next-Page')
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed the `gem kaminari` correctly? Can you ensure that `@posts = Post.page(1).per(5)` `<%= paginate @posts %>` is working?

Comment: Prehaps you using `link_to_next_page` helper somewhere outside of rails templates?

Comment: @railscard Yes, I'm using it in my controller. I need to get the next-page link and add it to the header of my response. Is that possible?

Comment: have you refer this video explain very nicely.. http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari?view=comments

Comment: If you want to put RFC 5988 Link headers, consider using [api-pagination](https://github.com/davidcelis/api-pagination#api-pagination)

Comment: I ended up doing my own pagination, this library didn't do what I was expecting it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def paginate(query)
   query.offset!((@page-1) * @per_page)
   query.limit!(@per_page+1)

   result = query.to_a

   if (result.size > @per_page)
     result.pop
     response.headers['Link'] = CREATE_NEXT_AGE_LINK_HERE
   end

   result
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Link helpers are not accessible into controllers. You can include entire helper module into your controller, but better use `view_context` to access particular helper method:

```
query = Posts.page(1).per(5).includes(author: :profile)    
link = view_context.link_to_next_page(query, 'Next-Page')
```

Good luck!

Comment: It no longer crashes but the next page link is blank